# Tensorflow landmark heatmap

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to draw landmark heatmaps with tensorflow.
My current approach is using `tf.scatter_nd` like this:

```
    def draw_lmarks(x):
        def draw_lmarks_inner(x2):
            return tf.scatter_nd(x2[0], x2[1], shape=(IMGSIZE, IMGSIZE))
        ret = tf.map_fn(draw_lmarks_inner, x, dtype="float32")
        return tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(ret, axis=0), [IMGSIZE, IMGSIZE, 1])
    return tf.map_fn(draw_lmarks, [locations, vals], dtype="float32")
```

But this is quite slow as i have to create an IMAGESIZE*IMAGESIZE image for each batch times landmarks.
So i poked around and found `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` which i could use like:

```
    img = tf.zeros((IMGSIZE,IMGSIZE), dtype="float32")
    def draw_lmarks(x):
        return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(img, x[0], x[1])
    imgs = tf.map_fn(draw_lmarks, [locations, vals], dtype="float32")
```

Which allows me to only generate batch_size images which runs considerably faster.
... BUT, this doesn't use the highest values at one point but instead simply overwrites.
There is the `tf.scatter_max` function which sounds like what i need but this seems to expect different shaped inputs.
Is there a way to use the second approach but instead of overwriting values takes the maximum value at one point ?

Shapes:
`location` = (-1, 68, 16, 16, 2)
`vals` = (-1, 68, 16, 16)

To visualize:
This is what the second (faster) function returns:
[image]
while i need something like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be much better off by first setting the seeds of your landmarks and then convolve the result with your heatmap template. Something like

```
import tensorflow as tf

num_loc = 10
im_dim = 32
locations = tf.random.uniform((num_loc, 2), maxval=im_dim, dtype=tf.int32)
centers = tf.scatter_nd(locations, [1]*num_loc, (im_dim, im_dim))
heatmap  = tf.nn.conv2d(centers[None, :, :, None], heatmap_template[:, :, None, None], (1, 1, 1, 1), 'SAME')[0, :, :, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't try it out yet but that sounds like the better approach actually. Since the bounty is running out i did send that out, but will accept after i investigated how well it actually works.